# Questions regarding Drawer menu and onClick

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

So for the last couple of days I've been trying to do some basic stuff in AndroidStudio, but I've noticed that even the basic stuff doesn't work. I think the reason is that I followed the YouTube tutorial to make a NavigationDrawer to have a classic menu. But thanks to this, I'm not able to roll out a button in any "submenu". It first started with maps, where I couldn't even put a Marker on the map and the whole thing didn't work. Next I tried to make an ImageButton, that didn't work and then I found out that the classic Button doesn't work either. Everything in MainActivity.java works, but when I make MorningActivity.java with putting layout.id.fragment_morning in it doesn't work.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mcdonaldscoupons;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private Intent Home;
    private Object NavigationUI;
    boolean isPressed = false;
    public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }
    }

    //Funkčnost fragmentů *START*

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_morning:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new MorningFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_afternoon:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new AfternoonFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_info:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new InfoFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_map:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new MapFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_other:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new OtherFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                String sharebody = "Podívej co Vojtí vytvořil!";
                String subject = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";
                i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sharebody);
                i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, subject);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Pošli to někomu ne?"));
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    //Funkčnost fragmentů *KONEC*
    //Double-back exit *START*

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        if (isPressed) {
            finishAffinity();
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    , "Klikni ještě jednou pro vypnutí!"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isPressed = true;
        }
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isPressed = false;
            }
        };
        new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
    }

    //Double-back exit *KONEC*
    //Other stuff

    private void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar) {
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/dark_green"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MorningActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mcdonaldscoupons;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class MorningActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_morning, container, false);

        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.test_product);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.test_product:
                Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "TEST",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_morning.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_morning"
    tools:context="com.example.mcdonaldscoupons.MorningActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/test_product"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="-85dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-139dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/test_product"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_product"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="2x McMuffin Menu"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MorningFragment.java**

```
package com.example.mcdonaldscoupons;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class MorningFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_morning, container, false);
    }
}
```

**drawer_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="Domů" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_morning"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_morning"
            android:title="Snídaně" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_afternoon"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_afternoon"
            android:title="Obědy" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_other"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_other"
            android:title="Různé" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Ostatní">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_map"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
                    android:title="Mapa mekáčů" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_info"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
                    android:title="O aplikaci" />
            </group>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:title="Sdílet" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have a MorningActivity which extends a Fragment class, is that on purpose? I would expect that to be an extension of AppCompatActivity.

Otherwise try to move the logic to the OnViewCreated method and only inflate the layout in the OnCreateView as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment?hl=en#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))

> It is recommended to only inflate the layout in this method and move logic that operates on the returned View to onViewCreated(View, Bundle).

It seems from watching your code snippets that the MorningActivity is never used or called, I do see the MorningFragment is being called in the MainActivity. But because the MorningFragment does not have any logic in it's class I expect you would only see the layout but when you press the button nothing would be triggered.

If that is the issue you can remove of the Morning Activity and move the logic from the button press listener to your fragment in the OnViewCreated method. Example:

```
public class MorningFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_morning, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        view.findViewById(R.id.test_product).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "TEST",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

At last, when you create a new project you can also select a template eg a Navigation Drawer Activity. Maybe you can compare it with your current project to see where the differences are.

Comment: The thing is, I found a tutorial where it wasn't using a template, but explained step by step. I wanted to make it so that in MainActivity there would be some general stuff, in MorningFragment just to make the navigation drawer work, and in MorningActivity there would be stuff related to the Morning fragment. So should I put the button in MorningFragment and delete MorningActivity?

Comment: The MorningFragments "lives" in the MainActivity because you place it in the fragment_container of the layout of the MainActivity. So the MorningActivity is never being used.  Yes you can put the button click listening logic in the MorningFragment, after that you should be able to see the Toast. Keep in mind that you might have to use the OnViewCreated method in the Fragment to register the button listener as mentioned in previous message.

Comment: so I tried it the way you wrote it, but it still doesn't do anything when clicked. I removed the MorningActivity and put your code in MorningFragment.java

So what now?

Comment: Just to verify, when you click in the navigation drawer, the MorningFragment shows up but when you click on the button nothing happens? Or does the MorningFragment not even show up when you click in the navigation drawer on the specific item?

Comment: When I click Morning in that navigation drawer it normally shows, but button isn't working.

Comment: Could you paste your drawer_menu.xml in your post? Then I can try to reproduce it. The MorningFragment  pasted in my answer works, so the problem seems to be somewhere else

Comment: i eddited the post

Comment: it fixed itself now